# AS3/AIR device landscape or portrait?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

On startup I want to check whether the device is in portrait or landscape mode, so far I have:

```
var startOrientation:String = stage.orientation;
        trace('startOrientation: '+ startOrientation);
        if (startOrientation == "default")
        {


        }
        if (startOrientation == "upsideDown")
        {


        }
```

But this doesnt tell me if its landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do :

```
trace(stage.orientation);
```

I get "rotatedRight"

stage.orientation can be one of :

```
public static const DEFAULT : String = "default";
public static const ROTATED_LEFT : String = "rotatedLeft";
public static const ROTATED_RIGHT : String = "rotatedRight";
public static const UNKNOWN : String = "unknown";
public static const UPSIDE_DOWN : String = "upsideDown";
```

There is also the stage.deviceOrientation property which can be used to determine the physical orientation of the device.

Comment: The question is specifically asking for portrait/landscape mode... orientation, OTOH, provides positioning of device wrt how it was designed to held normally e.g. there are devices with hard keyboard which have their default orientation as landscape.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so somehow the above posted "Answer" literally only answers exactly what the person with a question already knew... stage.orientation does not let you know if its landscape or portrait....

this may not be exactly what your looking for... but how about something like?

```
var isLandscape:Boolean = this.stage.stageWidth>this.stage.stageHeight;
```